# How to fetch data from parse.com and render it to table using AngularJs

Tags: collections, parse-platform, promise

I am trying to fetch data stored in parse.com collection. I am using Parse Javascript SDK to call the service asynchronously as following:

```
    ctrl.factory('TLDs', function($q){

    var query = new Parse.Query(Fahras)// Fahras is the Parse Object initialized earlier in code
    query.equalTo("type", "Domain")
    var myCollection = query.collection()

    return {
        fetchDomains: function(){
            var defer = $q.defer();

            myCollection.fetch({
                success : function(results) {
                    defer.resolve(results.modles);
                    console.info(results.models)
                },
                error : function(aError) {
                    defer.reject(aError);
                }
            });
            console.info(defer.promise)
            return defer.promise;

        }
    }
}) // end of factory topDomains
```

I have a simple table to show the fetched data

```
<div id="showdomainshere"> {{domains}}</div>

    <table id="domains_table" class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Domain</th>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Subjects</th>
            <th>Instances</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="table_body">
        <form id="edit_row" class="form-inline">

                <tr ng-repeat="item in domains">
                    <td><span>{{item.attributes.arTitle}}</span>
                    </td>

                    <td><span>{{item.attributes.domainCode}}</span>
                    </td>

                    <td><span>{{subclasses}}</span>    
                    </td>

                    <td><span>{{instances}}</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>

        </form>

        </tbody>
    </table>

</div> <!-- end of main div -->
```

And hereunder the controller I ma using to render the view:

```
ctrl.controller('Home', ['$scope','TLDs',function($scope, TLDs) {

    $scope.domains = TLDs.fetchDomains()


}])
```

Using console.info I can see that the result is fetched and I can go through the array of returned models as expected. Problem is that $scope.domains never been updated and as a result the table never been rendered

Comment: Fortunately I can figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately I am able to figure it out.

The controller should be like:

```
ctrl.controller('Home', ['$scope','TLDs',function($scope, TLDs) {
    TLDs.fetchDomains().then(function(data){
        $scope.domains = data
    })
}
```

While the factory itself should be like:

```
ctrl.factory('TLDs', function($q){
    var query = new Parse.Query(Fahras)
    query.equalTo("type", "Domain")
    var myCollection = query.collection()

    return {
        fetchDomains: function(){
            var defer = $q.defer();

            myCollection.fetch({
                success : function(results) {
                    defer.resolve(results.models)
                    return results.models
                },
                error : function(aError) {
                    defer.reject(aError)
                }
            })

            return defer.promise;

        }
    } }) // end of factory
```

Comment: Would you be interested in an alternative solution as another answer? (Yours is perfectly fine by the way, nothing wrong about it. One might think it suffers from the deferred anti pattern but because of how parse promises behave and they're not a part of the digest cycle - I understand why you'd want to do this)